# Issue with the modification of Blog category view in Joomla

Tags: php, templates, joomla, blogs, categories

I'm using JSN Epic template with Joomla 3.2.3. I tried to ask the template developer, but they said that this is not something that they could help me with.

For several days I'm trying to came up with solution in which the displayed dates in the Blog category shows the publish and expiration date. Unfortunately in the edit page there is no option for the Expiration date, just for publish and create. For me it is acceptable to change the create date and use the epiration date in its place and to change the language file so that it will show the correct label.

So i tried to modify the */html/category/blog_item.php* and to change *created* into *publish_down* or in other words like this:

```
<?php if ($params->get('show_create_date')) : ?>
<p class="createdate">
<?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_CREATED_DATE_ON', JHTML::_('date',$this->item->publish_down, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC2'))); ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Unfortunately the blog category layout is still untouched even after cache wipe.
I did the same one on two rows for the article view in */html/article/default.php* and it works fine:

```
<?php if ($params->get('show_create_date')) : ?>
<p class="createdate">
<?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_CREATED_DATE_ON', JHTML::_('date',$this->item->publish_down, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC2'))); ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I also tried the same with the core files, but with no luck either.

Is it defined anywhere else what to display in the blog category which i should change to take effect?

The other posibility was to create a custom field but after I defined it in the xml, the administrator form, the front end administrator and the template itself it happend that it didn't save the desired value, so i restored the backup of the files and continued with searching for solution with less coding.

Curently my best option is to use the publish_down because I also put Auto Archive extension which with spend me lots of explainations about what to do with the articles.

I also want to say that for the purpose of the website K2 or other content manager is not an option... For this website I prefer to use the default article system, but it's too complicated to explain why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Never change core files, your changes will just be erased with the next security update (and there's always going to be another update).
2. You should upgrade to the latest 3.3.x release as it includes many bug fixes and a few security fixes.
3. You specify the override was at `/html/category/blog_item.php` is this relative to the templates  directory i.e. `/templates/jsn_epic` or `/templates/jsn_epic_pro` if using the paid version?
4. Do you have a typo in the override path? It should include the component e.g. `/templates/jsn_epic/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php` if this isn't a typo and you've put the override in the wrong location it's likely that template has one that is being used and therefore explains why the changes you made to the core files are showing up.

*Another thought occurs to me, the latest versions of Joomla use layouts for the display of the **info block** which contains the date…* I don't have a 3.2 installation around but in 3.3 it loads the layout file `/layouts/joomla/content/info_block/publish_date.php`. Does 3.2 use layouts?

Comment: I was using "bracket"template path"bracket" before the override. Indeed the issue was with the layouts. After i changed the create_date.php everything is working fine. Thank you very much!